# clustering word in sentences in openrefine

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-cleaning, openrefine

I'd like to cluster words in a text file with rows like this:

```
number queries waiting support representatives become available
query numbers
```

More specifically, I want to replace words with their cluster representatives without changing the sentences otherwise.

What I'm trying to do is: 
1. split my column at spaces into more columns, each with a 1 word/row 
2. cluster all columns
3. merge the columns back

But this is very tedious. I'd like to hear about an easier and perhaps more elegant solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A probably better solution is to create a record for each row, "split multivalued cells" by space, cluster, and then join by space.

**Example :**

[image]